# SSH Client Closed on Command Error

Tags: bash, ssh, command, sshd

I am using Debian or Windows with Putty to connect to a remote Debian machine via SSH. The remote machine (Debian) behaves differently from the other SSH servers I know so far.

Whenever I run a command in the SSH console that failes, the connection is closed and the SSH client exits.

An example:

1. I log into the remote machine.
2. I execute cd /not-existing-directory.
3. The SSH client reports the server has closed the connection.

What may be the reason for this behavior and what can I do about it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your remote shell is bash (or Bourne-like), you likely have the `errexit` option turned on. The option instructs the shell to exit immediately if a "simple" command (such as `cd`) returns with an error.

Confirm, after you log in, by running:

```
echo "$-" | grep e
```

If the option is turned on, you'll see a line of text containing an `e`. If not, no text will be returned.

Alternatively, run:

```
set -o|grep errexit
```

If the option is turned on, you'll see:

```
errexit         on
```

If not, you'll see:

```
errexit         off
```

To turn the option off, run:

```
set +o errexit
```

or

```
set +e
```

For more information about `errexit`, see [Shell Command Lanugage - set](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#set)

Comment: Thanks a lot, the problem was a script containing `set -e`.